# SqlAlchemy and getting roles for my user through double relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables:

```
profile
  id, int, pk
  name...

role
  id, int, pk
  name
  ...

profilerole
  role_id     int, pk, foreign_key to role.id
  profile_id  int, pk, foreign_key to role.id
```

I want to write something to load the roles information and I currently have the following profile class:

```
class profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    enabled = Column(Boolean)
    verified = Column(Boolean)
    deleted = Column(Boolean)

    # this is the line I need help with...
    roles = relationship('roleprofile'
                 primaryjoin="and_(profile.id==roleprofile.id",
                 backref="profile")
```

The line above will give me roles information from the table `roleprofile` but what I would like it to give me is the roles from the `role` table.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

**Update**

Using this relationship:

```
roles = relationship('role', secondary=roleprofile, backref='profiles')
```

Why does it work to define this:

```
roleprofiles = Table('roleprofile', Base.metadata,
                  Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('role.id')),
                  Column('profile_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id'))
                  )
```

when this does not:

```
class roleprofile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roleprofile'

    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
    profile_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, name, created_by, last_updated_by, created=datetime.now(), last_updated=datetime.now()):
        self.name = name
        self.created = created
        self.created_by = created_by
        self.last_updated = last_updated
        self.last_updated_by = last_updated_by
```

When defining the association using `roleprofile` when already defined I get an error so they seem to be the same but only the first works. The class gives me the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard many-to-many relationship easily expressible in SQLAlchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many

You need to specify intermediate table as a `secondary` argument to `relationship`. In the simplest case there is no need to provide explicit `primaryjoin`, SQLAlchemy can figure out join criteria from metadata by itself.

```
profile_roles = Table('profilerole', Base.metadata,
    Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('profile_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id')), primary_key=True)


class Profile(Base):
    ...
    roles = relationship('Role', secondary=profile_roles, backref='profiles')
```

If you already have defined a declarative model for intermediate table, you can specify `<modelclass>.__table__` as a `secondary` argument instead of using SQLAlchemy core. But maybe you don't need full blown model for this table anyway: SQLAlchemy knows it needs to create it with `metadata.create_all`, and relationship can be manipulated through the collections interface.

Comment: That worked. Can you please also have a look (I updated the post) at why I need to create a `Table` when I've already defined the roleprofile model?

Comment: How do I add another upvote? I just found my old question and, now wiser, could understand fully what you wrote. Thanks again :-)